# Test Azure Staging Cloud Service behind TrafficManager and Alias

Tags: wcf, azure, ssl, dns, staging

I have a few WCF Web Services that I would like to test in Azure's staging area instead of deploying directly to the production area.

Here's the setup:

I have two cloud services https://1.cloudapp.net and https://2.cloudapp.net.  These cloud service endpoints are endpoints in a traffic manager https://mycloudapps.trafficmanager.net.  I have a DNS alias of https://mycloudapps.com mapped to the traffic manager url.

My client is setup to establish an SSL connection using the certificate for https://mycloudapps.com.

When I deploy to staging I edit my host file to use the staging ip to point to https://mycloudapps.com and if I ping https://mycloudapps.com I get the staging areas ip returned.  Yet when I call the services with my test client I am still hitting the endpoints behind the traffic manager url.

Additionally, I have tried mapping the traffic manager url to the same virtual ip of the staging environment - but I get the same result.

How can I call wcf services in Azure's staging environment in this scenario?

I haven't had much luck on the web... Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your host file is mapping mycloudapps.com to your staging IP, then that should be reflected by your test client also (assuming it's running on the same machine).  Possibly there's a DNS caching issue, I suggest running 'ipconfig /flushdns' and trying again.

You said you "mapped the Traffic Manager URL to the same virtual IP of the staging environment"...how *exactly* did you map your Traffic Manager profile to your staging service?  Traffic Manager works with domain names, not IP addresses directly.  I suggest using a tool like [digwebinterface](http://digwebinterface.com) to view the name resolution path and see how it is being directed towards your production rather than staging service.

Note that your staging service has different URLs than your production service (they look something like .cloudapp.net).  To use Traffic Manager with a staging slot, this is the URL you will need to configure in Traffic Manager.  To add such an endpoint to Traffic Manager, you will need to specify it as an 'external endpoint', following [these instructions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/azure-traffic-manager-external-endpoints-and-weighted-round-robin-via-powershell/).

Comment: I had already tried running dns flush and yes the client should reflect the ip in the host file, but it's not that is the problem.                                            You said you "mapped the Traffic Manager URL to the same virtual IP of the staging environment"...how exactly did you map your Traffic Manager profile to your staging service? Through the host file: IP myscloudapps.trafficmanager.net - I wouldn't expect that this would/should work...

Answer (score 0):

In that case, it sounds like the issue is that your browser is ignoring your hosts file.  I'm not an expert in that area, but it looks like you should be able to [find a solution online](https://www.bing.com/search?q=browser%20not%20using%20hostfile&form=EDGENT&qs=PF&cvid=ddc508e918be498485cd262b6ce2cacc&pq=browser%20not%20using%20hostfile&elv=ALolML20G8NalFweEyWRpbv2qSYQKnVNiXa4dj6nWLsx).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help I resolved the issue.  And I'm not testing with a browser.